# I'm having trouble extracting the right data in the right order from an XML file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing, lxml

Here's the code snippet that I wrote:

```
from lxml import etree as lxmlET
lxmltree = lxmlET.parse('sample.xml')
for names in lxmltree.xpath("/data/country/name"):
    print(names.text)
    for element in lxmltree.iter('country'):
        for element2 in lxmltree.iter('rank'):
            print(element2.text)
```

The output that I need :

NAMEWSF
2

3

4

5

NAMEWSF2

6

7

8

9
NAMEWSF3

10

The output I'm getting:
NAMEWSF
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
NAMEWSF2
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
NAMEWSF3
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

Here's the XML File : sample.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <name>NAMEWSF</name>
        <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
        <rank updated="yes">3</rank>
        <rank updated="yes">4</rank>
        <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <name>NAMEWSF2</name>
        <rank updated="yes">6</rank>
        <rank updated="yes">7</rank>
        <rank updated="yes">8</rank>
        <rank updated="yes">9</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <name>NAMEWSF3</name>
        <rank updated="yes">10</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

I tried using both xml and lxml, but I couldn't find something that'd help me in the documentation, I think it's just a matter of code structure, I'm new to programming so I'm still trying to get it right

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are probably looking for something like this:

```
for country in lxmltree.xpath('//country'):
   print(country.xpath('.//name/text()') + country.xpath('.//rank/text()'))
```

Output:

```
['NAMEWSF', '2', '3', '4', '5']
['NAMEWSF2', '6', '7', '8', '9']
['NAMEWSF3', '10']
```